# Build error when trying to compile Chess.app

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I have downloaded `Chess.app` from [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1085/). When I run `xcodebuild install` I get an error:

```
fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CFLogUtilities.h' file not found
#import <CoreFoundation/CFLogUtilities.h>
        ^ 1 error generated.
```

The same error occurs when Building within XCode.

I have looked in `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/` and, sure enough, `CFLogUtilities.h` is not present. I see that it's available to download from [Apple's Open Source Website](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFLogUtilities.h), but I feel like if it's linked in an app bundled with the OS, it should be installed by default, or at least after installing XCode + Command Line Tools.

Do I have to manually download and bundle the header file in order to build the project, or am I missing something?

Comment: [Here's the file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFLogUtilities.h), if it helps any.

Comment: @Undo Where should I put the file? I moved it in to the CoreFoundation framework folder, but am still getting the same error. Should I set the permissions some special way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what OS version you are using, but to compile this on 10.9 simply change `CFLogUtilities.h` to `CoreFoundation.h`.

you also either need to build the `CrashReporterClient.a` library and add it to the project, or remove it from the "link with libraries" build setting for the target.

a shell script will fail because `iconcompiler` is missing, but you can comment out that script line with a `#` and run just fine. I will leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how best to restore the app icon.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do all of this (download, untar, compile) from a script, and I'm not sure what you're suggesting is possible from a script. Are you able to compile the app on your machine by any chance?

Comment: @JoshWhittington yes, I successfully compiled and ran from my 10.9 machine after doing what I said.

Comment: In the XCode project, it shows that library as being "optional". Is there any way to force the build setting to obey this preference? Either in XCode or xcodebuild?

Comment: @JoshWhittington it is a static library and you are specifying it in the link list so it is required to build. just do what I said and remove it from the list.